# Reverse a string giving same string

Tags: javascript

This question has been asked before however I wanted to know what is wrong with my solution (I can Google a solution but more interested in learning what I am doing wrong). I want to reverse a string without using a major builtin function that does it. Below is my code but it returns the same string,

```
s="hello";
var opp=s;
for (var i=0; i< s.length; i++)
{
   opp[i] = s[s.length-i];        
}
alert (opp);
```

Comment: _"This question has been asked before"_ Then there is already an answer to your question...

Comment: Strings are immutable: you cannot assign to an index. `str[n]` is read-only.

Comment: @AlexK: I am new to JavaScript. I could do this in C/C++, PHP

Comment: An apple tastes of apple but an orange does not.

Answer (score 2):

Your code returns the same string because in JavaScript strings are frozen. Any attempt to modify string will be ignored. Instead you need to build new string according to your rules.

You can update your code by assigning `opp` to empty string: `var opp = ''` and then pushing chars to it in reverse order: `opp += s[s.length-i]`.

Also I found a bug in your code. What will return the first iteration? It will try to access char at missing position: `s.length - i = s.length - 0 = s.length`. Because in JavaScript strings and arrays are zero indexed the max char index in your string will be `s.length - 1`. You are trying to access `s.length`.

Comment: Thanks. I should probably split the string before dong anything.

Answer (score 0):

Strings are [immutable](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Data_structures#Primitive_values): you cannot assign to an index. `opp[i]` is read-only.

An alternative is to use an array:

```js
s = "hello";
var opp = [];
var len = s.length - 1;
for (var i = 0; i <= len; i++)
   opp[i] = s[len - i];        

console.log(opp.join(""));
```

Comment: Can you explain why `i<=s.length` and not `i<s.length`?

Answer (score 0):

with reduce

```
'some word'
  .split('')
  .reduce(({str, tail}, char, i, word) => {
    return {tail: tail - 1, str: str + word[word.length + tail]}
  }, {str: '', tail: -1})
  .str
```